# Is there a way to make_ref() for spawned processes in erlang?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have tried to make references to spawned processes in erlang in several ways in order to make them compatible with the logging of `From` in a call to `gen_server`. So far I have tried `P1ID = {spawn(fun() -> self() end), make_ref()},` in order to capture the structure of `from()` as stated in the documentation about `gen_server:reply`: [erlang documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#reply-2)  I have not yet succeeded and the documentation about `make_ref()` is rather scarce.

Comment: Why are you trying to build such a structure manually? The idea of the `From` structure is that it uniquely identifies _a particular message_, not a server/process. That reference is created right before sending the message to the server so that the response coming from the server can be uniquely tied to the message sent to it.
To use it in `gen_server:reply/2`, the idea is that you _picked it up_ on `handle_call/3` and you didn't reply immediately from that function (you used `{noreply, State}` and then, at some other point, you can use `gen_server:reply/2` with that `From` that you caputred

Comment: The short answer is for testing. And that is because I have problems with doing what you describe for part of the code, whereas for other part of the code it works. But that will be another post.

Comment: @BrujoBenavides , I have now made a post that covers what I refer to in the comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209559/how-can-i-reply-to-two-processes-in-the-same-handle-call-3-of-the-gen-server-in , as a the 'longer answer' to your question. I would however still like to know how to `make_ref()` for a spawned process it that is possible.

Comment: Still… the ref is not _for a spawned process_, that's the whole point. The ref is for _a particular message_. From a spawned process, you can try using just `make_ref()`, but I'm still not sure how would that help you. In any case, I'll read the other question now.

Comment: That was a good conc3eptual clarification of the purpose of `make_ref()`

Comment: How can you break down and test `gen_server` calls with TDD by making a minimal code that ensure a specific callers message has the effect intended. This would be another way of asking the  question my original question implies, I guess.

Comment: Furthermore, could you give me some better conceptual clarification of the idea of sendingen several messages with a reference. What the gen_server does is then to use pang `!` to send specific messages, and these messages are then pattern matched by a tag or time-stamp ?

Comment: I think the best I can do is refer you to these 2 articles that I wrote: https://medium.com/erlang-battleground/erlang-behaviors-4348e89351ff (The second one is linked within the first one).

Comment: About how `gen_server` works, you can check OTP code directly… 

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/619438e6b6edef3bef5c0145d781bc458b7e5bc3/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L245-L275

It doesn't call `make_ref/0` explicitly anymore (it creates a monitor for the process being called now) but the pattern-matching on `receive` is still the same.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I shall look forward to see the articles. Did you see my response to your response to the other post?

Answer (score 1):

were you attempting to built that {Pid, Ref} tuple in order to test the handle_call() gen_server callback from your tests?

if yes, you should not test these gen_server internals directly. instead add higher level functions to your module(that will call the gen_server call/cast/.. functions) and test those

spawn() already returns a pid() so there was no reason to return self() from from the spawned process.

Hope it helps

Comment: "if yes, you should not test these gen_server internals directly. instead add higher level functions to your module(that will call the gen_server call/cast/.. functions) and test those" how to do so if the server has postponed a call, and you want to test that both callers receive an answer simultanously (that is within the same `handle_call`).

Comment: from your question i didn't realize there were 2 callers and any postponing involved. gen_server call's are sync calls, so they will be processed in order(there is no simultaneity). could you post some of your code because i don't understand what you're trying to achieve :)