# Why does gen_server:reply/2 work in some instances while causing timeouts in others

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

I have problems getting `gen_server:reply` to work in some but not all cases in my code although the code seems to me to be similar in structure from the areas it works and it doesn't. And I don't know if this is due to some conceptual misunderstanding or incompleteness of the `gen_server:reply/`.

I have created MRE code as seen below (with EUnit tests and all ready to plug and play) I experience that the test function `setup_test()` succeeds whereas the function `setup_test_move_rs_both_receive()` doesn't. The latter creates a 'hanging'/time out for the `mve_rps_game:move/2` function.

Why is that, and how can I deal with it?

```
-module(mve_rps_game).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

-export([init/1, handle_cast/2, handle_call/3, start/0, setup_game/2, move/2, test_all/0]). 

%------------------------Internal functions to game coordinator module

make_move(Choice, OtherRef, PlayersMap, CurMoveKey, OtherMoveKey) ->
    case maps:get(OtherMoveKey, PlayersMap, badkey) of
        badkey ->            
            PlayersMap2 = maps:put(CurMoveKey, Choice, PlayersMap),
            {noreply, PlayersMap2};
        OtherChoice ->
            io:format(user, "~n Choice, OtherChoice, CurPid, OtherRef: ~w ~w ~w ~w~n",[Choice, OtherChoice, self(), OtherRef]),
            gen_server:reply(OtherRef, Choice),
            {reply, OtherChoice, PlayersMap}           
    end.
%-----------------Init game-coordinator and its handle_call functions

init(_Args) ->    
    PlayersMap = #{}, 
    {ok,PlayersMap}.

handle_call({move, Choice}, From, PlayersMap = #{start:= {P1Ref, P2Ref}}) ->    
    {P1id, _} = P1Ref,
    {P2id, _} = P2Ref,
    {CurId, _} = From,
    case CurId of
        P1id ->            
            make_move(Choice, P2Ref, PlayersMap, p1_move, p2_move);
        P2id ->
            make_move(Choice, P1Ref, PlayersMap, p2_move, p1_move);
        _Other ->
            {reply, {error, not_a_player}, PlayersMap}
    end;

handle_call({set_up, Name}, From, PlayersMap) ->
    case maps:is_key(prev_player, PlayersMap) of
        %Adds req number of rounds as a key containing player name and ref for postponed reply
        false ->           
            PlayersMap2 = maps:put(prev_player,{Name, From}, PlayersMap),
            {noreply, PlayersMap2};
        
        %Sends message back to previous caller and current caller to setup game
        true -> 
            case maps:get(prev_player, PlayersMap, badkey) of                
                {OtherPlayer, OtherRef} ->  
                    gen_server:reply(OtherRef, {ok, Name}),                    
                    PlayersMap2 = maps:remove(prev_player, PlayersMap),                    
                    %Make key start to indicate that game is going on, and with References to two players. 
                    PlayersMap3 = PlayersMap2#{start => {From, OtherRef}}, 
                    {reply, {ok, OtherPlayer}, PlayersMap3};
                _ -> 
                    {reply, error, PlayersMap}
            end        
    end.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%------------- CALLS to Rps game -------------------
start() ->
    {ok, Pid} = gen_server:start(?MODULE,[], []),
    {ok, Pid}.

setup_game(Coordinator, Name) -> 
    gen_server:call(Coordinator, {set_up, Name}, infinity).

move(Coordinator, Choice) ->     
    gen_server:call(Coordinator, {move, Choice}, infinity).

%--------------- EUnit Test section ------------

setup_test() ->
    {"Queue up for a game",
     fun() ->
             {ok, CoordinatorPid} = mve_rps_game:start(),
             Caller = self(),
             spawn(fun() -> State = mve_rps_game:setup_game(CoordinatorPid, "player1"),
                            Caller ! State end),
             timer:sleep(1000),             
             {ok, OtherPlayer} = mve_rps_game:setup_game(CoordinatorPid, "player2"), 
             ProcessState = 
                receive             
                    State -> State
                end,
            ?assertMatch(ProcessState, {ok, "player2"}),
            ?assertMatch({ok, OtherPlayer}, {ok, "player1"})            
     end}.

queue_up_test_move_rs_both_receive() ->
    {"Testing that both players recieve answer in rock to scissor",
    fun() ->
        {ok, CoordinatorPid} = mve_rps_game:start(),
        Caller = self(),
        spawn(fun() ->
            {ok, _OtherPlayer} = mve_rps_game:setup_game(CoordinatorPid, "player1"),
            State = mve_rps_game:move(CoordinatorPid, rock),
            Caller ! State
        end),
        timer:sleep(1000),
        {ok, _OtherPlayer} = mve_rps_game:setup_game(CoordinatorPid, "player2"),
        Result2 = mve_rps_game:move(CoordinatorPid, scissor),
        io:format(user, "Result2: ~w~n",[Result2]),    
        ?assertMatch(Result2, rock),
        ProcessState = receive
            State -> State
        end,
        ?assertMatch(ProcessState, win)    
        end}.

test_all() ->
    eunit:test(
      [
        setup_test()
        ,queue_up_test_move_rs_both_receive()
      ], [verbose]).
```

Comment: Are the rest of you able to reproduce the problem when you chuck in the MVE code I made?

Comment: Tiny detail, but you're ussing the params for `?assertMatch/2` in the wrong order. The proper way is `?assertMatch(WhatYouExpect, WhatYouGot)` (e.g., `?assertMatch(rock, Result2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finely figured out, and I was not even that far off in my other posts regarding the use and concept of `make_ref()` seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206252/is-there-a-way-to-make-ref-for-spawned-processes-in-erlang?noredirect=1#comment132752843_75206252). So the problem is based on a conceptual incompleteness of the `pid()` vs. `reference()` and `From` within `gen_server`.

The reason why the code causes a timeout is because the `gen_server:reply(OtherRef, Choice)` uses a reference that was saved in the `gen_server`s state in a former `gen_server:call/3`. Therefore it is trying to reply to a call that already was answered, whereas the new call is not, because the reference/tag of the new call isn't stored.

Comment: I adjusted my answer with that same info :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to solve your issue but I can point you to the place in the code where things are going astray…

When you call the function `make_move/5` from the first clause of `handle_call/3`, you're passing is as the last parameters either `p1_move, p2_move` or `p2_move, p1_move`, but those keys are never added to the `PlayersMap` so `maps:get/3` will always return `badkey`.

In that case you're not replying to the client (i.e. you return `{noreply, PlayersMap2}` and you don't keep the `From` from `handle_call/3` anywhere… So, in essence, you never respond to any call to `mve_rps_game:move/2`. That function uses `infinity` as its time-out value for `gen_server:call/3`, so… eventually the tests themselves timeout.

I'm not entirely sure what the fix *should* be, but you should probably start by checking how/when to respond to your client in `make_move/5` (or in the first clause of `handle_call/3`).

### Edit: Found the Issue

(For an explanation of this change, check the comments below)

The way to solve the issue is to keep track of the last message received by each user and not just the first one.
Making the following changes you'll be able to move past the timeout issue. Your tests will still fail, but for a different reason…

```erlang
    case CurId of
        P1id ->            
            make_move(Choice, P2Ref, PlayersMap#{start := {From, P2Ref}}, p1_move, p2_move);
        P2id ->
            make_move(Choice, P1Ref, PlayersMap#{start := {P1Ref, From}}, p2_move, p1_move);
        _Other ->
            {reply, {error, not_a_player}, PlayersMap}
    end;
```

The main chang is the adjustment of `start` within `PlayersMap`. As a matter of fact, that item should be called `last_message` or something along those lines, but I would leave that up to you.

Comment: Hi Brujo, and thanks for the response. I will have to state though, that either I don't understand your diagnosis or I just don't agree with it. If I were never able to return anything bout badkey, it would never get to `OtherChoice` however if you run the code the `io:format/2` there prints perfectly indicating that `OtherChoice ` was reached. This is the case while a timeout occurs (due to the deliberate choice of `infinity` in the call as you commented on). Something else must be going on.

Comment: Yeah, the second time you call that function (i.e., `Result2 = mve_rps_game:move(CoordinatorPid, scissor)`), it works.
The one that doesn't work is the first time (`State = mve_rps_game:move(CoordinatorPid, rock)`). You're never calling `gen_server:reply/2` for that `gen_server` call.
That's why `Caller ! State` is never evaluated and thus your last receive times out.

Comment: Oh, I see… you actually intended to send that reply using `gen_server:reply(OtherRef, Choice),` but since that `OtherRef` was stored in the state when you handled the `{set_up, Name}` message, and not updated when you handled `{move, Choice}`, you're not responding to the right message/client.